# OData Client Code Generator for Authenticated Feed (Excel Service)

Tags: excel, authentication, odata, t4

How does one generate an OData Client Proxy for an authenticated service? In my case, I'm connecting to the Excel Service Restful OData feed for a spreadsheet in O365/SharePoint online.

I can access the metadata and feed in my browser after authenticating, but I'm hoping to use the OData Client Code Generator installed in VS2015 (C#). There is no option/prompt for credentials, just a 403 error. I've tried logging into VS with the same office account, and also opening up the feed (authenticated) in the browser in VS but no luck.

I am able to save the metadata xml to my project. I was wondering if perhaps I can get access to the T4 template file and reference the metadata in file instead of through the URI?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/06/23/how-to-enable-authentication-for-metadata-documents-in-the-odata-client-code-generator.aspx) shows how to modify the OData code gen tool to support authentication, but this is pre-Visual Studio 2015. The new connected service add-in doesn't seem to have the same architecture so not sure this hack can work in 2015.